# Janusgraph with spring-data-gremlin

Tags: tinkerpop, janusgraph, tinkerpop3

I am using the JanusGraph 0.5.3 with Cassandra as backend. With [spring-data-gremlin](https://github.com/microsoft/spring-data-gremlin) version 2.3.0 along with spring-boot:2.5.0, tinkerpop:3.4.6, I am trying to connect to Janusgraph. A vertex could be successfully created and using gremlin console, I could query and view the vertex. But with spring-data-gremlin and tinkerpop, the de-serialization step is failing. Following the other posts and discussion, I used different ones including [GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/driver/ser/GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0.html). The error message is

```
 at [Source: (byte[])"{"requestId":"2c9fc2cc-de02-4f19-b2d3-64d20c96530a","status":{"message":"","code":200,"attributes":{"@type":"g:Map","@value":["host","/172.19.0.1:35744"]}},"result":{"data":{"@type"
:"g:List","@value":[{"@type":"g:Vertex","@value":{"id":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":1000},"label":"Product","properties":{"name":[{"@type":"g:VertexProperty","@value":{"id":{"@type":"janusgraph:RelationId
entifier","@value":{"relationId":"215s0t-rs-35x"}},"value":"Product-11","label":"name"}}],"_classname":[{"@type":"g:"[truncated 235 bytes]; line: 1, column: 404] (through reference chain: java.util.Linke
dHashMap["result"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["data"])                                  
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:271)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:1718)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.GraphSONTypeDeserializer.deserialize(GraphSONTypeDeserializer.java:194)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.GraphSONTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromAny(GraphSONTypeDeserializer.java:101)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer.deserializeWithType(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:312)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap(MapDeserializer.java:529)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:364)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:29)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.GraphSONTypeDeserializer.deserialize(GraphSONTypeDeserializer.java:219)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.GraphSONTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromAny(GraphSONTypeDeserializer.java:101)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer.deserializeWithType(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:312)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap(MapDeserializer.java:529)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:364)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:29)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.GraphSONTypeDeserializer.deserialize(GraphSONTypeDeserializer.java:212)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.GraphSONTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(GraphSONTypeDeserializer.java:86)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserializeWithType(MapDeserializer.java:400)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:68)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.readValue(DeserializationContext.java:760)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.readValue(DeserializationContext.java:747)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.AbstractObjectDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractObjectDeserializer.java:48)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.GraphSONTypeDeserializer.deserialize(GraphSONTypeDeserializer.java:212)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.io.graphson.GraphSONTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromAny(GraphSONTypeDeserializer.java:101)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.deserializeWithType(StdDeserializer.java:136)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:68)
```

and the json, it is trying to serialize it is

```
[Source: (byte[])"{"requestId":"2c9fc2cc-de02-4f19-b2d3-64d20c96530a","status":{"message":"","code":200,"attributes":{"@type":"g:Map","@value":["host","/172.19.0.1:35744"]}},"result":{"data":{"@type"
:"g:List","@value":[{"@type":"g:Vertex","@value":{"id":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":1000},"label":"Product","properties":{"name":[{"@type":"g:VertexProperty","@value":{"id":{"@type":"janusgraph:RelationId
entifier","@value":{"relationId":"215s0t-rs-35x"}},"value":"Product-11","label":"name"}}],"_classname":[{"@type":"g:"[truncated 235 bytes]; line: 1, column: 404] (through reference chain: java.util.Linke
dHashMap["result"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["data"])
```

Using gremlin console, I serialized the vertex and the json of the vertex is

```
{
  "id": {
    "@type": "g:Int64",
    "@value": 1000
  },
  "label": "Product",
  "outE": {
    "also_bought": [
      {
        "id": {
          "@type": "janusgraph:RelationIdentifier",
          "@value": {
            "relationId": "215st9-rs-8sut-8hk"
          }
        },
        "inV": {
          "@type": "g:Int64",
          "@value": 11000
        }
      },
      {
        "id": {
          "@type": "janusgraph:RelationIdentifier",
          "@value": {
            "relationId": "215t7h-rs-8sut-99c"
          }
        },
        "inV": {
          "@type": "g:Int64",
          "@value": 12000
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": [
      {
        "id": {
          "@type": "janusgraph:RelationIdentifier",
          "@value": {
            "relationId": "215s0t-rs-35x"
          }
        },
        "value": "Product-11"
      }
    ],
    "_classname": [
      {
        "id": {
          "@type": "janusgraph:RelationIdentifier",
          "@value": {
            "relationId": "215sf1-rs-3yd"
          }
        },
        "value": "com.divvet.store.productgraph.domain.Product"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This does not match up with the spring-data-gremlin serialization which has vertex nested two level down

```
[Source: (byte[])"{"requestId":"2c9fc2cc-de02-4f19-b2d3-64d20c96530a","status":{"message":"","code":200,"attributes":{"@type":"g:Map","@value":["host","/172.19.0.1:35744"]}},"result":{"data":{"@type"
:"g:List","@value":[{"@type":"g:Vertex","@value":{"id":{"@type":"g:Int64","@value":1000},"label":"Product","properties":{"name":[{"@type":"g:VertexProperty","@value":{"id":{"@type":"janusgraph:RelationId
entifier","@value":{"relationId":"215s0t-rs-35x"}},"value":"Product-11","label":"name"}}],"_classname":[{"@type":"g:"[truncated 235 bytes]; line: 1, column: 404] (through reference chain: java.util.LinkedHashMap["result"]>java.util.LinkedHashMap["data"])
```

The properties in remote-graph.properties is

```
gremlin.remote.remoteConnectionClass=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteConnection
gremlin.remote.driver.clusterFile=conf/remote-objects.yaml
gremlin.remote.driver.sourceName=g
```

and remote-objects.yaml is

```
hosts: [localhost]
port: 8182
serializer: {
  className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0,
  config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
```

For the serializer, I tried with all the serializers that are listed [here](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/driver/ser/Serializers.html)
Please let me know if you need more details and how to resolve this.

Comment: After giving it a try for few days, removed the spring-data-gremlin and continuing with tinkerpop and janusgraph driver.
Usage of spring-data-gremlin is deprecated in favor and azure cosmos and so it makes sense to not to use it for janusgraph.